# Inserção de valor float em um JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

Estou com a seguinte situação, tenho um objeto chamado `Item`, com uma variável de valor nele.
Na hora que vou inserir o valor no objeto json ele muda de 1 ou 2 casas depois da virgula para 15 casas depois da virgula.

Ex: o valor é 8.9 e muda pra 8.899999618530273 quando colocado no json.

Item:

```
public class Item {
    private float valor;

    public void setValor(float valor) {
        this.valor = v;
    }
    public float getValor() {
        return this.valor;
    }
}


JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
float v = item.getValor();  // --> Aqui o valor de 'v' é 8.9
obj.put("Valor", v);   // --> Aqui após inserido no json, olhando no debugger o valor já é 8.899999618530273
...
```

Não sei se isso é algo normal do `JSONOBbject` fazer, mas causa inconsistência de dados.

Tem alguma forma de fazer com que o valor seja o mesmo que o do modelo?

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma seria converter seu float para String formatando as casas decimais e usar o construtor [JSONObject(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29) para passar o valor

Segue exemplo:

```
float v = item.getValor();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.format("{\"Valor\": %.2f}", v);
```

Outra forma seria convertendo para String e passando via método put

```
 obj.put("Valor", (String.format("%.2f", v)));
```

Comment: Eu pensei nisso também, mas no meu caso tem mais itens para colocar no objeto json, aí não sei se seria útil. Ou teria que fazer o format em uma única `String` pra todos os campos, que são mais de 10.

Comment: Editei a resposta com uma forma que possa te ajudar

Comment: Nesse caso ele fica como uma string e não como um número. Mas mesmo assim, obrigado. Vou usar o valor em `double` mesmo, fiz testes e na hora de receber o valor no servidor ele volta a arredondar pra 8.9 (?).